# On the definition of continuity.

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I didn’t quite understand what continuity means, first i thought that the definition of continuity is the same thing as the domain of definition of the function, and what made me think like that is the definition of continuity in calculus $1$, it says :

Let $f$ be a function, $f$ Is continuous at $a$ iff $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$$
So by this definition we can say that $f$ is continuous in any point in the its domain .

But when i saw some YouTube videos on that topic some of them say that the rigorous definition (using $\epsilon - \delta$ Definition) is :

Let $f:A\to \mathbb R$, where $A\subseteq \mathbb R$, $f$ Is continuous at $a\in A$ Iff $\forall \epsilon >0 , \exists \delta >0$ Such that if $$|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$$
I don’t have a problem with the $\epsilon - \delta$ part of the definition, my problem is that the definition assumes that $a\in A$ but how could a function not be continuous in a point belongs to its domain of definition ?

Comment: Let $A = \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = 0$ if $x < 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ if $x \geq 0$, this is clearly discontinuous at the point $0$ in the domain...

Comment: well im not confortable with piecewise functions

Comment: @Yassir Then let $A=(0,\infty)$ and $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$.

Comment: Perhaps you think that continuity is same as "being defined". No it is not. Continuity is a new idea which is based on limits and conveys much more than just being defined.

Comment: Also there is a standard result that an elementary function is continuous wherever it is defined, so an example of a discontinuous function must be based on piece wise definition. Probably this is the reason which made you equate continuity with "being defined".

Answer (score 1):

If $f\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ is defined by$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x=0\\0&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$then the domain of $f$ is $\Bbb R$, but $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0\ne f(0)$. So, no, it is not true a function $f$ is continuous at every point of its domain. Actually, if you defined $f$ by$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x\in\Bbb Q\\0&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$then $f$ is discontinuous at *every* point of its domain.

Comment: Does it exist some counterexample without using piecewise functions ?

Comment: Sure:$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{1+x^2}\right)^n,$$which turns out to be equal to my first $f$.

Comment: @Yassir I suppose you want to ask whether there exists an *elementary* counterexample. Well, all elementary operations such as addition, subtraction, multiplication, division as well as all elementary functions such as exponential, logarithm, trigonometric functions are continuous in their domain - so, no, you need *something* non-elementary (a piecewise definition, a limit, a characteristic function, ...) if you want to *explicitly* write down a function that is not continuous in its domain.

Comment: ‘all elementary functions are continuous in their domain of definition ‘ can you write down that in your answer @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: No, since that is *not* part of my answer. And if you have a precise definition of “elementary function” in mind, my congratulations. I surely don't.